# There is angular acceleration about the other. Something seems wrong with this question

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

> A disc is kept on a rough surface with linear velocity v, equal to the product of angular velocity and radius (same as what happens during pure rolling. Find the time after which it stops. Given the mass of the disc is $m$ and radius is $r$.

[image]

If we take a line perpendicular the plane of the disc passing through the point of contact as the axis, then the normal, weight, friction all pass through the axis, so there is no net torque and no net angular acceleration which means there will be no linear acceleration (linear acceleration is the product of angular accleration and radius) and therefore the disc will keep going non-stop.

But what if we take a line perpendicular to the plane of the disc passing through the center of mass of the disc as the axis, then the friction produces some torque and there is an angular acceleration resulting the body to stop.

Where am I wrong? Is there something wrong with the question?

Comment: There is a small force of friction that will eventually decelerate the disc to a stop.

Answer (score 0):

Hey so firstly I wanna point out that I don't really get why you speak about taking lines through stuff to set up your equations. But I'm going to assume your problem can be 2 dimensional and we therefore only need the following equations:

$\sum\vec{F}_x = \frac{d\vec{p}_x}{dt}$

$\sum\vec{F}_y = \frac{d\vec{p}_y}{dt}$

$\sum\vec{T}_O = \frac{d\vec{L}_O}{dt}$

What you need to realize is that a disc you are describing is rotating on the ground at constant speed and with constant rotation speed, that means that no net force is acting on it, by the first newton law.

$\sum\vec{F}_x = 0$

$\sum\vec{F}_y = 0$

$\sum\vec{T}_O = 0$

now while the one along y is trivial, the one along x actually highlights the problem in your drawing. Since the disk is subject to no acceleration, the friction force is actually $0$. That's because since the disk is rotating, the contact point speed is $0$.

This is then also consistent with the fact that you can sum torques at any point in your system and always get back $0$.

Hope this helps

Comment: How can a body roll on a surface without an external force? There must be some friction to make it roll, otherwise it would slide.

Comment: the friction must only be there when you are accelerating the disc with yet another force on its center of rotation. Once it has constant speed, no external forces act on it

Answer (score 0):

There is a net force along the horizontal direction. So, there is acceleration of the center of mass. There is also a torque around the CM so there is angular acceleration as well. Both the velocity of CM and the rotation around the CM slow down until the object stops.
If you want to use an axis that does not pass through CM then the things don't work in the same simple way.